# How to perform Broken-line regression analysis in R?

Tags: r

I have the following data:

```
Treatment   Dose      Value
FeSo4       200       104.17
TQ1          6        98.17
TQ2          9        92
TQ3         12        86.67
TQ4         15        77.33
TQ5         18        71.33
TQ6         21        74.83
TQ7         24        82.17
```

How can I do Broken-line regression analysis of this data in R to get the graph as below:

[image: The image is included in following link]

Comment: What did you try already?

Answer (score 1):

The best way to fit linear models by segments in R is to use CRAN package [segmented](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/segmented/).
In what follows, I have created a new column, coercing column `Treatment` from class `factor` to its integer codes.

```
library(segmented)

df1$Num <- as.integer(df1$Treatment)

fit <- lm(Value ~ Num, df1)
summary(fit)

seg <- segmented(fit, seg.Z = ~Num, psi = 6)

plot(Value ~ Num, df1)    # plot the points
plot(seg, add = TRUE)     # plot the broken line
abline(v = seg$psi[2])    # plot the vertical at the breakpoint
```

**Data.**

```
df1 <- read.table(text = "
Treatment   Dose      Value
FeSo4       200       104.17
TQ1          6        98.17
TQ2          9        92
TQ3         12        86.67
TQ4         15        77.33
TQ5         18        71.33
TQ6         21        74.83
TQ7         24        82.17
", header = TRUE)
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I want to know how do you set psi =6?

Comment: @M.R.Wani By visual inspection of the graph, `plot(Value ~ Num, df1)` shows a breakpoint near point `Num == 6`. SO that seemed to be a good starting value for `psi`. In the code above I only plot the data after fitting the model, maybe I should change that.

Answer (score 0):

A different approach is to first find the threshold and then fit a regular `lm()` model:

```
library(SiZer)
df <- read.table(text = "
Treatment   Dose      Value
FeSo4       200       104.17
TQ1          6        98.17
TQ2          9        92
TQ3         12        86.67
TQ4         15        77.33
TQ5         18        71.33
TQ6         21        74.83
TQ7         24        82.17
", header = TRUE)
df$Num <- as.integer(df$Treatment)

thr.pwl = piecewise.linear(df$Num, df$Value,
                             middle = 1, CI = FALSE, 
                             bootstrap.samples = 1000, sig.level = 0.001)
thr.pwl

[1] "Threshold alpha: 6.30159931424453" #This is the threshold you need
[1] ""
[1] "Model coefficients: Beta[0], Beta[1], Beta[2]" #The estimates here are the same as in model.pwl, however, with lm() you can include also other independent variables
(Intercept)           x           w 
  111.48333    -6.63000    13.97001

model.pwl <- lm(Value ~ Num*(Num >= 6.30) + Num*(Num < 6.30),
            data = df) 
summary(model.pwl)
```

And you can plot it as:

```
plot(thr.pwl)
abline(v = thr.pwl$change.point)
```

However, with `piecewise.linear()` you can only us one threshold, while with `segmented()` more of them.